# UV Unwrapping makes a mess and misses faces

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have a relatively simple mesh, that looks like this (a couple of tight faces and loop cuts due to subdivision smoothing):

[image]

However when I try to UV unwrap it, it's a whole mess and even misses most of the faces:

[image]

When I select a face I can see where it is located on the texture map:

[image]

But other faces aren't located on it at all:

[image]

What could have went wrong here?

I made sure to select all vertices of the mesh before unwrapping, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Could you upload the blend file? There is something strange in the images like if the selected plane was not the rendered one. You can use this link to upload: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/p22VD8zE

I am still a beginner so expect the worst xD

Comment: Additionnaly to Martynas answer, there are two problems, I think. doubled vertices in your mesh and ngons. That causes the subdivision modifier to give a weird result and so textures are distorded.

Comment: @lemon Yeah, I'm still trying to get better at mesh topology. The version I uploaded here is the 3rd actually, the previous ones were much worse xD

I just found it weird some faces didn't have texture at all.

Comment: I'll most likely make another attempt and try to avoid ngons as best as I can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to mark all the seems correctly and it will umwrap nicely. Make sure you mark all the small edges that could interfere with the unwrapping and try again.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> while in edit mode to call the Edge menu where you can find Mark Seam.

[image]

It is also a good idea to apply scale of the object to get expected results when unwrapping. You can do that with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> with the object selected in object mode:

[image]

Comment: After adding some seams and unwrapping, all other faces were mapped! It's still a mess though, most likely because I have bad topology, but at least all faces have textures now! Thanks!

Comment: You can also try different methods of unwrapping in the F9 Adjust Last Operation panel. In some cases Conformal and in some Angle Based.

Comment: Excuse me but can you tell me where I can find that panel?

Comment: Hit F9 while hovering the mouse over 3d view. It's on by default and will float at the bottom left corner of the 3d view as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! The smart unwrapping method actually did a really nice job!